# sizeof float (3.0) vs (3.0f)

Tags: c, sizeof

What is the difference between sizeof(3.0) and sizeof(3.0f)

I was expecting both of them to give the same result (sizeof float)..but its different.

In 32 bit machine,gcc compiler,
sizeof(3.0f) =>4
sizeof(3.0)  => 8

Why so?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because 3.0 is a double. See [C syntax Floating point types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Floating_point_types).

> Floating-point constants may be
>   written in decimal notation, e.g.
>   1.23. Scientific notation may be used by adding e or E followed by a decimal
>   exponent, e.g. 1.23e2 (which has the
>   value 123). Either a decimal point or
>   an exponent is required (otherwise,
>   the number is an integer constant).
>   C99 introduced hexadecimal
>   floating-point constants, which follow
>   similar rules except that they must be
>   prefixed by 0x and use p to specify a
>   hexadecimal exponent. Both decimal and
>   hexadecimal floating-point constants
>   may be suffixed by f or F to indicate
>   a constant of type float, by l or L to
>   indicate type long double, or left
>   unsuffixed for a double constant.

Comment: Both decimal and hexadecimal floating-point constants may be suffixed by f or F to indicate a constant of type float, by l or L to indicate type long double, or left unsuffixed for a double constant.

=> its too fast to get an answer here :)

Answer (score 10):

- 3.0f is float (4 bytes)
- 3.0 is double (8 bytes)

[more info](http://irc.essex.ac.uk/www.iota-six.co.uk/c/b3_float_double_and_sizeof.asp)

Answer (score 6):

3.0 is a `double`, not a `float`.

`doubles` are twice as wide as `float`s.

**EDIT**: 3.0d is only in C#

Comment: There is no 'd' floating point suffix ('l' and 'L' give long double, 'f' and 'F' give float and absence of a suffix gives a double)

Comment: In IEEE754 `double` is twice as wide as `float` ; C does not require IEEE754 however.